# Can't install fail2ban on Centos 7.1

Tags: centos

I am trying to install fail2ban on my centos 7.1 server

I did:

```
 yum install epel-release
    yum install fail2ban
```

But i am getting some error messages:

```
 yum install epel-release
    Package epel-release-7-5.noarch already installed and latest version
    Nothing to do

-----

[root@elliot ~]# yum install fail2ban
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: mirror1.34sp.com
 * base: centos.mirror.transip.nl
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: centos.mirror.transip.nl
 * updates: centos.mirror.transip.nl
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fail2ban.noarch 0:0.9.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: python-inotify for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: gamin-python for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fail2ban.noarch 0:0.9.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package gamin-python.x86_64 0:0.1.10-16.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: gamin = 0.1.10-16.el7 for package: gamin-python-0.1.10-16.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgamin-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: gamin-python-0.1.10-16.el7.x86_64
---> Package python-inotify.noarch 0:0.9.4-4.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fail2ban.noarch 0:0.9.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 2.6 for package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch
---> Package gamin.x86_64 0:0.1.10-16.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
           Installed: python-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 (@updates)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
           Available: python-2.7.5-16.el7.x86_64 (base)
               python(abi) = 2.7
               python(abi) = 2.7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@elliot ~]#
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem?
I also tried to install it on a new server, and I had no problem on that server

P.S if you want you can login in to my PC

Comment: What does "rpm -q epel-release" say?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might have two `epel-release` packages installed - one for EPEL 6, one for EPEL 7. Your first `yum` command shows `epel-release-7-5` is installed, your second `yum` command is pulling in `fail2ban-0.9.2-1.el6` which is from EPEL 6 (not 7). If this is the case, you should see two results from `rpm -q epel-release`. If you then `yum remove` the EPEL 6 release package and issue a `yum clean all`, you should then be able to `yum install fail2ban` successfully.